# How to test a network protocol?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, protocols, command-line-interface

I'm currently doing some research including comparing efficiency, accuracy and flexibility of different transport protocols such as TCP, UDP and a new protocol based on UDP we're currently designing. I'm aware of the differences in general, the facts like TCP is more accurate while UDP is faster. What I'm looking for is more specific indicators those can be used to validate and evaluate a protocol.

Also considering the changing network environment, the evaluation cannot be convincing without a series of testing and capturing, which means the testing need to be ran automatically and get overall performance indicator. So I prefer to use some CLI tools.

Comment: I think the first thing to do is define your goal more specifically.  What is it in particular that you want to measure?  Data throughput?  Latency?  Robustness in the face of packet loss or endpoint malfunction?  The impact of the protocol on the performance of the network as a whole?  CPU usage on the sending and receiving ends?  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new Message Analyzer from Microsoft, a new network protocol, system message, and ETW event analysis tool, complete with extensive filtering, graphics, remote capture, asset sharing; and it is Powershell-enabled: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649776.aspx